# How to check if Mercurial tag already exists, from command-line?

Tags: linux, bash, mercurial

How do I check from a command-line script whether a Mercurial tag already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check for the existance of the tag XXX (and ignore mercurial's output):

```
hg log -rXXX
```

It will return error code 0 if the tag exists and 255 if it does not.

Comment: This checks whether a tag exists locally. To check whether it exists remotely, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/41156418/14731.