# How to check if remote repository contains tag?

Tags: command-line, mercurial

How do I check from the command-line whether a local tag `mytag` exists on a remote repository and is pointing to the same changeset?

I believe that I can solve this problem once I solve the following sub-problems:

1. [How do I find out which changeset added a tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41156538/14731)
2. [How to find out whether a remote repository contains a changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41156468/14731)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the aforementioned sub-questions, I believe the following will work:

```
// Get the changeset that the tag points to
def referenced = $(hg id -q -r ${tag})

// Get the changeset that added the tag
def addedTag = $(hg log -r children(${referenced}) --template {node})

// Check whether the remote repository contains the changeset
def tagFound = $(hg outgoing -r ${addedTag})
```

Comment: A little late to the party but what language is this script?