# How to find out whether a remote repository contains a changeset?

Tags: mercurial

How do I find out whether a remote repository contains a particular changeset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

`hg outgoing -r <changeset>` returns 1 if the changeset exists remotely.