# How do I find out which changeset added a tag?

Tags: mercurial

If I invoke `hg tag test` then `hg id -r test` returns the changeset that the tag points to, but the tag was actually added by the subsequent commit.

**How do I look up the changeset that actually added a tag** (as opposed to the changeset that the tag points to)?

Is it safe to assume that it will always be the child of `hg id -r <tag>`?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume its always the direct child of the tagged rev is the commit making the tag, as tagging a non head rev, shows this isn't true. I guess you could hg annotate the .hgtags file and look for the line that contains the tag.

Comment: @Tom That is a very good idea. While we're on the topic, can you think of an easier way to implement stackoverflow.com/q/41156418/14731?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a tagged changeset only has one child (the one that adds the tag) then the following commands will get the changeset that adds the tag:

```
// Get the changeset that the tag points to
def referenced = $(hg id -q -r ${tag})

// Get the changeset that added the tag
def addedTag = $(hg log -r children(${referenced}) --template {node})
```